# Dynamically update title of Design Support TabLayout

Tags: arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport, android-tablayout

is there a way to dynamically update the title of a tab in a Design Support TabLayout? I tried adding a method in the Adapter which changes the contents of the ArrayList which holds the titles of the tabs and notify the adapter but the tab titles don't change to the new title.

Adapter:

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        fragmentTiles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTiles.get(position);
    }

    public void setFragmentTiles(int index, String title) {
        fragmentTiles.set(index, title);

        Log.e("ARRAY", fragmentTiles.toString());
    }
}
```

I am changing the content of the title ArrayList like this:

```
adapter.setFragmentTiles("New title 1");
adapter.setFragmentTiles("New title 2");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But this doesn't work. Do I have to update the ViewPager or the TabLayout as well?

Answer (score 5):

What's worked for me is to use the setText method on the Tab:

> i.e. tab.setText(...); // where ... is CharSequence or resId

Looking at the methods available to the TabLayout you can get the desired Tab instance of an index/position:

> e.g. tabLayout.getTabAt(...); // where ... is int.

As far as I can tell, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter just calls the `getCount()` of the adapter as opposed to what one might expect of refreshing the title.

Hopefully that helps or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it asap